# Weight Threshold error when creating a Deduplication Rule

Tags: dedupe-rules

This is on CiviCRM 5.36.

I try and create a rule with, say, First Name and Last Name, both having a weight of 10.  If I set any Threshold greater than 10 so as to require both to match, I get the error:

`Weight Threshold to Consider Contacts 'Matching':  11  Total weight must be greater than or equal to the Weight Threshold.`

I first saw this when trying to change the usage on an existing rule which had worked previously.

Answer (score 2):

This has been [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20078/files) and will be part of next 5.36 release this week.

You can either wait for the never version release or apply patch from [here](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/20078.patch).

HTH

Pradeep

Answer (score 0):

Known error.  Fixed in Commit   https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/commit/b1212927a34f1086e6911fea5405595a40c5bcf9